# Android button comparing

Tags: java, android, button, compare

I've got very very basic problem in Java (Android) writing. Here it is, I've got code:

```
public void WriteValue (View sender){
   Button bt=(Button)sender;
}
```

WriteValue is performed, when user click button. And now I want to compare button which user clicks, with button that Id I know. Something like

```
 if(UserButton==ClearButton) Display.setText("0");
```

Thanks for help
Tux:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just compare ids.-

```
public void WriteValue (View sender) {
    Button bt = (Button)sender;
    if(bt.getId() == R.id.clearButtonId) {
        Display.setText("0");
    }
}
```

Comment: @user2948835 Just know there is no reason for the extra line to cast to a `Button`. You can just use `sender.getId()`. If this is the answer that best worked for you please accept by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

step 1 : make your Class implement OnClickListener

step 2 :

```
// global variable
Button btOne ,bTwo;
```

step 3 :

```
// in onCreate() method
btOne = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btOne);
btTwo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btTwo);

btOne.setOnClickListener(this);
btTwo.setOnClickListener(this);
```

step 4 : implement method from interface

```
puvlic void onClick(View v)
{
if(v==btOne)
{
// do work for btone
}
if(v==btTwo)
{
// do work for btTwo
}
}
```

Comment: It is better to compare `id`s than the actual `object`.

Comment: Not sure about what? The `id` doesn't change after its compiled

Comment: i know the id wont change , but i am saying , not sure whether hashcode comparison is better or id comparison

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to cast the `View` to a `Button` here. You can simply get the `id` of the `View` clicked which is the `param` sent to the function (assuming this is an `onClick()` function as defined in xml or by setting the `listener` in Java). So it could be something like this

```
  public void WriteValue (View sender)
  {
       int id = sender.getId();   // get the id of the View clicked
       swith (id)                 // switch logic on that id
       { 
           case (R.id clearButtonId):  // if the clearButton was clicked do this
                Display.setText("0");
                break;
           default:
                 Display.setText("Some other String);
                break;
       }
  }
```

You could also use `if/else` instead of a `switch` but this is more readable, IMHO. This easily allows you to add more logic for other `Button`s.

Also consider using Java naming conventions. According to this code, I assume `Display` is a `TextView` or `EditText` so it should start with a lower-case letter (ex. `display`).